# How can I copy system shared libraries to a conda package?

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, anaconda, conda

I'm making a conda package that is C++ code that is dependent on libboost and libopencv, and is then exposed to Python wrappers. I have libboost and libopencv installed on my system in a particular way.

I want to redistribute these libraries along with my package (this is for internal use only). I use plain make.

I'm not sure how to package my code in a way that shared libraries are copied and used from within the package. So that even if I send my package to a computer with no dependencies installed, it will still run. I want to prioritize my shared libraries even if there are other system libraries installed. Think of it as a standalone package.

I'm not sure if I have to use CMake to build my stuff in the right way - does anyone have any example that I can use?

Comment: `I'm not sure if I have to use CMake to build my stuff in the right way` - Nothing forces you to use CMake. You may use `make` or any other build  tool. As for CMake, it has support for packaging. But explaining it in one post would be too broad. As usual, Stack Overflow is **badly suited** for "where to start" questions.

Comment: @Tsyvarev thanks for answering. well this is not primarily oriented towards asking about cmake, but rather bringing in shared libraries into a self contained conda package. The reason i was asking about cmake was because i see a lot of people using it in conda and i was wondering whether this is made easier. however the primary intention of this question was around packaging of a conda library.